# Attaching VS Code Debugger to C# process from shell script

Tags: linux, shell, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

"Launch with Debugger" isn't working on my project for reasons I assume are platform-related.
As a workaround, I've been using a bash script to build and run the project and attaching the VS Code debugger manually.
Attaching the debugger manually is a bit tedious: is there a way to attach it via my shell script?

Comment: There's definitely not anything for the purpose _built into_ bash, so any answer you get will be generic to any/every shell, not bash-specific. No need to tag this bash, then.

Comment: (As to substance: gdb and its frontends such as ddd definitely can be told to attach from the command line, so if VS Code can't do this, there are plenty of other debuggers that can).

Comment: You're right, since this feature would be through VS Code rather than bash. Changed tags and title to reflect that. Thanks!

Comment: I'll also look at gdb to see if it has the functionality I need.

Comment: You may also wish to spend more time digging into why "Launch with Debugger" isn't working. I found that sometimes you have to tweak VSCode settings or possibly adjust your environment to get the built-in commands working correctly. Sometimes it's as simple as updating your PATH.

Comment: When I tried digging deeper into troubleshooting `launch.json` and `tasks.json`, I didn't manage to find any documentation that told me more than VSC's autocomplete for those them.

Comment: As for running the program, since I'm building on Linux, my compiled binaries have no file extension, which makes VSC throw a fit; since there's no file extension, it tries to find the compiled binary name in my PATH. If I try using the default settings, it tries to load a `dll` in the project and locks up, and if I try renaming the output binary, it tells me it's the wrong file (duplicate of `xxx`).

Comment: I opted to just write the shell script I'm using instead of wasting company time trying to wrestle with VSC configurations, and it's frankly been working better for me than doing builds and running them in VSC with my window layout.